# FireStore: Update Anomaly

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a scenario where each user in my Firebase database can have their own set of recipes, and they can also add recipes from other users to their fav_recipes. Now, I have made changes to an attribute of one of the recipes (For example I change name of recipe), and I need to update all the user's fav_recipes (with updated name) that include this specific recipe. Here is my firestore schema.

[image]

How can I efficiently achieve this in my Firebase database using Swift?

Comment: Single source of truth! You should only have to update in 1 spot. You shouldn’t have several other copies of the same thing you can use DocumentReference to link favorites to the actual recipe

Comment: The question is a little vague - "made changes to an attribute". Can you please be more specific in what that means? In other words, changing the attribute of one recipe should have no impact elsewhere, as long as the code knows about it. Details please on what is mean by "attribute" and the code being used to read that data so we can provide a solution.

Comment: @loremipsum Yes this can be solution to my problem if I use DocumentReference link for users.

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific built-in operation to perform such a bulk update. You will have to:

1. Perform a query to get the affected documents
2. Loop over the results
3. Update each document in turn

Comment: is there any other schema that can be followed ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you ask if there is any other way, somebody might think of something else - but there's no built-in operation to perform such a bulk update.

Answer (score 1):

Single source of truth! You should only have to update in 1 spot.

You shouldn’t have several copies of the same thing you can use `DocumentReference` to link favorites to the actual recipe.

```
fav_recipes: [DocumentReference]
```

or something like

```
fav_recipes: [Recipe.ID]
```

So you can query the recipe using an `ID` that does not change.